# Jquery opacity toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the div containing the login form to disappear when clicking the "Create an account" anchor then I would like to be able to reverse the process by clicking the "sign in" anchor on the registration form using Jquery.

I think I properly linked Jquery and the Js file in the head.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="script/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
  <script src="script/javascript.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here's the new html

```
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
      <button>create</button>
      <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="" class="signin">Sign In</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <button>login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="" class="create">Create an account</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
```

And here's the new javascript.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.signin').on("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.register-form').fadeOut();
     $('.login-form').fadeIn();
  });

  $('a.create').on("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('.login-form').fadeOut();
     $('.register-form').fadeIn();
  });
)};
```

Clicking on the anchors does nothing by the way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML to this (I've added a class to each anchor).

```html
<div class="form">
    <form class="register-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
      <button>create</button>
      <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#" class="signin">Sign In</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <button>login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#" class="create">Create an account</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Then replace your jQuery to this...

```js
$('a.signin').on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.register-form').fadeOut();
   $('.login-form').fadeIn();
});

$('a.create').on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.login-form').fadeOut();
   $('.register-form').fadeIn();
});
```

Use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function in jQuery. It's much better for events like on-click etc.

Comment: It seems like the way to do it, but it doesn't seem to work or display properly in Chrome.
I'm using XAMPP and the .php file is my index, when inspecting in chrome it gives no error and both jquery.js and javascript.js are in the source menu.

Maybe something is wrong with my configuration or I missed something

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console at all? What's not working?

Comment: No, there is no errors in the Chrome's console, and when clicking the `<a>`nothing happens, except a # in the url but that's normal.

Comment: Have you added the jQuery code? It seems like the code isn't being executed at all because the `e.preventDefault();` should be stopping the `#` from being in the URL.

Comment: At least I thought I did, I edited the post to contain your updated version of the Jquery (pasted the whole javascript.js contents).

Another thing I noticed is that when go to localhost, javascript.js is in the sources, but when I click the register link and check sources again, jquery.js is still here but that's not the case for javascript.js

Comment: Are you including the jQuery include before the jQuery I posted above? Also, is it correctly within a document ready function or as is (like above)?

Comment: Thanks mate, I totally forgot to use the document ready, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, guess I forgot to use the `$(document).ready(function)`, then made a syntax error at the very end of my javascript.js because I wrote `)};` instead of `});`

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Once you link you html to jquery and javascript correctly, the above code toggles as expected.

Add the code below to you css file to hide the Registration form on initial launch of the web page.

`.register-form {
    display: none;
}`